# mapping the filter to a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

How do I map a filter to a JSP? I want when I first call the JSP a filter be invoked first and then the request be sent to JSP. How do I do that ?

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter-1</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Filters.Filter_1</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-1</filter-name>
    <!-- map the filter to jsp . How do I do that ?-->
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: you want it for a specific jsp or for all JSP?

Comment: @JigarJoshi how does that matter ? It is located in `web-pages` directory of the app

Comment: that matters to create the URL mapping for Filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add URL pattern that uniquely identifies your specific JSP call

```
<filter-name>Filter-1</filter-name>
<url-pattern>YourJsp.jsp</url-pattern>
```

Comment: can we also write the class name of the jsp. I mean the .class file formed after jsp is compiled

Comment: Yes it does which inturn has url pattern

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, is it possible to define filter url-pattern for two pages ?

Comment: @Mah you can use regex pattern there

Comment: @Jigar Joshi can you give example please ?